# Scala - How to iterate over tuples on RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD that contains tuples like this

> (A, List(2,5,6,7))
>
> (B, List(2,8,9,10))

and I would like to get the index of the first element where a specific condition between value and index holds. 
So far I have tried this on a single tuple test  and it works fine:

```
test._2.zipWithIndex.indexWhere { case (v, i) => SOME_CONDITION}
```

I just can't find how to iterate over all tuples in the list.. I have tried:

```
val result= test._._2.zipWithIndex.indexWhere { case (v, i) => SOME_CONDITION}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, "iterate" is the wrong concept here - it comes from the realm of imperative programming, where you actually iterate over the data structure yourself. Spark uses a functional paradigm, which let's you pass a *function* to handle each record in the RDD (using some *higher-order* function like `map`, `foreach`...).

In this case, sounds like you want to *map* each element into a new element.

To map only the right-hand side of your tuples (without changing the left-hand side), you can use `mapValues`:

```
// mapValues will map the "values" (of type List[Int]) to new values (of type Int)
rdd.mapValues(list => list.zipWithIndex.indexWhere { 
  case (v, i) => someCondition(v, i) 
})
```

Or, alternatively, using plain `map`:

```
rdd.map { 
  case (key, list) => (key, list.zipWithIndex.indexWhere { 
    case (v, i) => someCondition(v, i) 
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I get this error  `value indexWhere is not a member of Iterable[(Int, Int)]`

Comment: I'm assuming your input RDD is of type `RDD[(String, List[Int])]` - is that not the case? If so - what is it?

Comment: I would say it is but I am probably wrong.. The list members come from a wordcount. Is there a way to check the type of the object ? Or explicitly define its type ?

Comment: Of course - define it explicitly (e.g. `val myRdd: RDD[(String, List[Int])] = ...`) and check the compiler output - if you got it wrong, error message should be clear about what it actually is.

Comment: Well it seems that a map function I  used earlier changed somehow the type to iterable int. `found   : Iterable[Int]
[error]  required: List[Int]`

Comment: In that case you can call `toList` on the iterable and go on from there: `rdd.mapValues(iter => iter.toList.zipWithIndex...)`